# Extracting number of months from an interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT DATE_PART('month', '2018-05-31'::timestamp - '2018-02-24'::timestamp);
```

It returns 0! All the time. Why?

I am on PostgreSQL 10.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have:

```
t=# select '2018-05-31'::timestamp - '2018-02-24'::timestamp;
 ?column?
----------
 96 days
(1 row)
```

so:

```
t=# SELECT DATE_PART('day', '2018-05-31'::timestamp - '2018-02-24');
 date_part
-----------
        96
(1 row)
```

try:

```
t=# SELECT DATE_PART('month', justify_interval('2018-05-31'::timestamp - '2018-02-24'::timestamp));
 date_part
-----------
         3
(1 row)
```

I think the need of justifying interval prior to using it with `date_part` should be noted at
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT, to be clear - true...

Comment: you are amazing!! I was breaking my head and even tried casting into interval ...

Comment: yes, it looks a meant behaviour, but I think not intuitive one

Comment: @AlexZheda since this answer solved the problem I kindly ask you to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I have to wait for 5 minutes to accept it... not my fault that I cannot do it right away after I read and "mentally" accepted the answer

Comment: @AlexZheda I did not blame you, just reminded you to accept the answer in case you would forget it. It is very often that people do not accept the solution as the correct answer, so the aim of my comment was to prevent that, not assuming that it will happen in this case without my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Vao Tsun has explained why.

One good solution for you might be to use the `age` function, which formats the interval in years, months and days:

```
SELECT date_part('month', age('2018-05-31'::timestamp, '2018-02-24'::timestamp));

 date_part 
-----------
         3
(1 row)
```

That will return more accurate results, because it does not have to assume that every month has 30 days.

Comment: thank you Laurenz. I wish I could accept both answers because they do complement each other..